# whether $C=\{f \in C^2[0,1]: f(x)f'(x) > 0 \forall x \in [0, 1]\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

Determine whether the following set is open or not

$$||f||_{2,\infty}=sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|+sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)|+sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f''(x)|$$

(a) 
$$C=\{f \in C^2[0,1]: f(x)f'(x) > 0 for 0\leq x\leq 1\}$$

(b)
$$C=\{f \in C^2[0,1]: f(x)f'(x) > 0 for 0<x<1\}$$

I guess (a) is not open, (b) is open since x can be reached at $0$ and $1$

Is my guess right?

I tried to find a $\delta_g$ s.t.
$$||h-f||_{2,\infty}=sup_{x\in[0,1]}|h(x)-f(x)|+sup_{x\in[0,1]}|h'(x)-f'(x)|+sup_{x\in[0,1]}|h''(x)-f''(x)|<\delta_g$$
=>
$$h(x)>f(x)-\delta_g, h'(x) >f'(x)-\delta_g$$

But I don't know how the endpoint effect whether the set is open

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your guess, and your ideas about how to proceed with a proof.  This is not a site to ask people to solve your homework problems for you.

Comment: What is the topology on $C^{2}[0,1]$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy up to second derivative of the function f over $[0,1]$ exits and continuous.

Comment: That is the definition of the set. That is not the defintion of a norm or  a topology.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy clarify in the question,  the norm is the sup norm involved second derivative

Comment: It turns out that your guesses are both wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a), let $f \in C.$ There are two possibilites: Both $f,f'>0$ on $[0,1],$ or both $f,f'<0$ on $[0,1].$ Suppose it's the first case. Then there is a constant $r>0$ such that $f,f'>r$ on $[0,1].$ Verfiy that $B(f,r)\subset C.$ (Here $B(f,r)$ is the open ball with center $f$ and radius $r$ in $C^2[0,1]$ defined by the $C^2$-norm.)  The case $f,f'<0$ on $[0,1]$ is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the norm is $\|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}+\|f''\|_{\infty}$ you can prove that set in a) is open by showing that the map $f \to \inf \{f(x)f'(x): 0\leq x \leq 1\}$ is a continuous function on $C^{2}[0,1]$.

Answer for b): the set is not open. Consider $f(x)=x$. Clearly, this belongs to the given set and $ x -\frac 1 n$ to $x$ in the space. So every neighborhood of $f(x)=x$ contains elements which don't satisfy the inequality $f(x)f'(x) >0$ for $0 <x<1$.

Comment: I understand b, but I still confused (a). Why we use the map to the inf, and why the map is continuous, the set is open

Comment: For a continuous function $g$ the condition $g(x) >0$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$ holds iff its infimum is strictly greater than $0$. [This is because the infimum is attained]. For your second question use the fact that $g_n \to g$ uniformly implies $\inf \, g_n \to \inf \, g$.